# suggest in enchant.Dict(..) isn't accurate

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk

I want to achieve two parts :

1. I want to remove redundant letters that are existing in each string more than twice.
2. Check the best matched English word after processing first part on each string. I am using python so I used enchant.Dict("en") and also enchant.Dict("en").suggest(..)

For example:

```
Heelllllo should be Heello
Heeeeeeeey should be Heey
yessssssss should be yees
```

My problem  is in 2. For "yessssssss"
I have the suggested list of words:

```
['yes', 'less', 'mess', 'fess', 'jess', 'Hess', 'yeas', 'yens', 'yews', 'yes s']
```

So my question is "yes s" as the last word in the result isn't meaningful, so I need more accurate result, Does my approach right ?, should I consider change in part 1 ?